# How to read and update React Context from child with function components?

Tags: reactjs

In my App component I create a context(AuthContext) and define a state(authenticated) and a method to change state(setAuthenticated):

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './pages/Home.js';



export const AuthContext = React.createContext();
function App() {
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(true);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{authenticated, setAuthenticated}}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path={"/"} component={Home}  />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

From the child component(Home) I can log the value of `authenticated` but can not render it:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AuthContext } from '../App.js';

function Home(props) {
const { authenticated, setAuthenticated } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
console.log(authenticated);
console.log(setAuthenticated);

  return (
    <div>
        {authenticated}
        <button onClick={() => setAuthenticated(false)}>
          Logout
        </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

How do I render the value of `authenticated` inside my child component `Home`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React doesn't render `Boolean, null or undefined values`. Check the [documentation on it here](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored)

In order to render the authenticated value you need to convert it to string

```
return (
    <div>
        {authenticated.toString()}
        <button onClick={() => setAuthenticated(false)}>
          Logout
        </button>
    </div>
  );
```